# android app: Gmail cause app to crash after login

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app to log into Facebook, Twitter, Hotmail and Gmail accounts and have a combined inbox to view the feeds/messages. Everything was working fine until the 24 of Jan 2013, but after than the app crashes when login into the Gmail account. If login details are wrong app does not crash, if login details are right the app show the Toast "login successful" and than when moving into my combined inbox it crashes. 3 days ago' I run it again with no problems (didn't have any changes made to the code) than I was unable to login into Gmail again.
my code for the Gmail login is the following:

// Execute Gmail Login

```
public class GmailLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.Executing_Gmail_login,
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Executing Gmail login..",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... params) {
        username = params[0];
        password = params[1];
        return Gmail.doGmailLogin(params[0], params[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (result) {
            SharedPreferences gmailPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                    Const.GMAIL_PREF_NAME, 0);
            Utility.saveGmailPrefrences(gmailPreference, username, password);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.Gmail_Login_success,
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gmail Login succesful",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            gotoInbox();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.Invalid_login_try_again, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    //"Invalid login. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}//end of GmailLogin class
```

and here is the logcat relative to this problem:

```
02-09 11:17:28.187: I/Choreographer(759): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkRange(IMAPFolder.java:429)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessage(IMAPFolder.java:1365)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at javax.mail.Folder.getMessages(Folder.java:879)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.fyp.Gmail.getMails(Gmail.java:161)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.fyp.InboxActivity$RecieveGmail.doInBackground(InboxActivity.java:510)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at com.fyp.InboxActivity$RecieveGmail.doInBackground(InboxActivity.java:1)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-09 11:17:28.436: E/AndroidRuntime(759):  ... 5 more
02-09 11:17:28.956: I/Choreographer(759): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 11:17:29.446: I/Choreographer(759): Skipped 125 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 11:17:29.606: I/Choreographer(759): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I don't understand why it worked for nearly 2 months and than stopped working without importing any changes to the code

If anybody has any idea about this problem I'll really appreciate it

the Gmail.getMails method is the following:

```
 //Get mails from gmail.
public static Message[] getMails(final String username, final String password) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    // props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    // props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.imap.user", username);
    // User SSL
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory", 993);
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.imap.port", 993);
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }

    };

    Session sessioned = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

    Store store;
    try {
        store = sessioned.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        // FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        // Message[] unReadMessages = inbox.search(ft);
        int total=inbox.getMessageCount();
        Message[] unReadMessages = reverseMsgs(inbox.getMessages(total-15,total)); 
        //= inbox.getMessages(total,total-15);
        return unReadMessages;
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the Gmail.getMails(Gmail.java:161) method..

Comment: I edited the question and added the method you asked about.

Comment: post the line no 161 what is written on Gmail.java

Comment: line no 161 is the following:                                     Message[] unReadMessages = reverseMsgs(inbox.getMessages(total-15,total));